# How to remove border arround image

Tags: html, css, border

So I have a problem. I'm using sprites for the first time and now around them appear border, I tried to set border:none but it didn't work.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eddvinas/mKLE9/)

```
<div class="service">
<img href="image/icons.png" style="background-image:url('image/icons.png'); background-position:0 0; height:59px; width:59px; border:none"/>
</div>

.service {
position:relative;
float:left;
clear:left;
border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="service">
    <img href="image/icons.png" style="background-image:url('image/icons.png'); background-position:0 0; height:59px; width:59px; border:none"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.service {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the href, and change your img tag to a div like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/WtaXr/

```
<div class="service">
    <div style="background-image:url('image/icons.png'); background-position:0 0; height:59px; width:59px; border:none"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you could mark the question as resolved just incase somebody else comes along with the same issue that would be great! :)